# vbscript namedItem() change select dropdown

Tags: html, dom, drop-down-menu, vbscript

In [Excel VBA change option in the HTML select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963540/excel-vba-change-option-in-the-html-select-tag), I used the following code to change options within the `<select>` tag:

```
For Each objOption In objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")(0).GetElementsByTagName("td")(tdNode).GetElementsByClassName("txt_input1")(0).Options
    If objOption.Value = SelQ Then
        objOption.Selected = True
        objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")(0).GetElementsByTagName("td")(tdNode).GetElementsByClassName("txt_input1")(0).OnChange
    Else
        objOption.Selected = False
    End If
Next
```

This seems to work for web sites with nested `<table>` tags, but the web site was updated without the tags, so, to compensate for finding the selected option, I used this:

```
For Each objOption In objIE.Document.getElementById("frmProduction").elements.namedItem("WQ").Options
    If objOption.Value = strVal Then
        objOption.Selected = True
        objIE.Document.getElementById("frmProduction").elements.namedItem("WQ").onchange
        Exit For
    Else
        objOption.Selected = False
    End If
Next
```

This is giving me the following error: `Run-time error '5002': Application-defined or object-defined error`

I used the above solution because it worked in another Internet Explorer application that used `<frames>` tags, so I modified it a little:

```
objIE.document.frames("DemographicsIFrame").document.GetElementByID("DropDownPayerID").value = PayerID
objIE.document.frames("DemographicsIFrame").document.GetElementByID("DropDownPayerID").onchange
```

I've tried to get around it with no success. I can get the selected option to change, but that's it. It won't update the page with required info related to the selected option. In the example above, that's what the `onchange` event was used for...to change the page contents after the PayerID was updated.

Any advice on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were actually able to come up with a solution:

```
For Each objOption In objIE.document.getElementById("frmProduction").elements.namedItem("WQ").Options
    If objOption.Value = strVal Then
        objOption.Selected = True
        Set evtFiroz = objIE.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        evtFiroz.initEvent "change", False, True
        objIE.document.getElementById("WQ").dispatchEvent evtFiroz
        Exit For
    Else
        objOption.Selected = False
    End If
Next
```